# CakePHP Login Method Undefined

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I am using CakePHP to implement a register, login, logout system. However, once the user passes their credentials into the login this error message pops up:

> Error: Call to undefined method
>   Cake\Controller\Component\AuthComponent::login() File
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\sss_martinmeli_6.2b\src\Controller\UsersController.php
>   Line: 43

This is my UsersController

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\Event\Event;

class UsersController extends AppController {
    public function index(){
        //get an instance of the users table found in (src/Model/Table)
        $users = TableRegistry::get('Users');

        //get all users from the table
        $query = $users->find();

        //you can use the debug
        //debug($query->toArray());

        $all_users = $query->toArray();

        $this->set('users', $all_users);
    }

    public function register()
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $usersTable = TableRegistry::get('Users');
            $user = $usersTable->newEntity($this->request->data());

            if ($usersTable->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->set("Successfully registered!");
                return $this->redirect(["controller" => "Pages", "action" => "success"]);
            }
            else {
                $this->Flash->set("Error");
                $this->set('errors', $user->errors());
            }
        }
    }

    public function login()
    {       
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password'));
        }
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }

    public function isAuthorized($user)
    {
        // All registered users can add an entry
        if (in_array($this->request->action, ['view']) && (int)$this->request->params['pass'][0] == $user['id']) {
            return true;
        }

        return parent::isAuthorized($user);
    }

    public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);
        // Allow users to register and logout.
        $this->Auth->allow('login', 'register');
    }
}
?>
```

I cannot see why the AuthComponent::login() is not defined as this is how the Cookbook recommends that it is done.

Comment: And where exactly in the Cookbook does it recommend this? You may want to double check that you're looking at the correct docs.

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authentication-login-and-logout

Comment: As I said, double check what you're looking at... the top bar should give you a clue.

Comment: This does work, it always says invalid.
`if (!$this->Auth->user('id')) {
            if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                $user = $this->Auth->identify();
                if ($user) {
                    $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
                }
                $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password'));
            }
        }
        //if user is already logged in.
        else {
            return $this->redirect(["controller" => "Pages", "action" => "index"]);
        }`

Comment: @MartinMeli The code you are showing is from CakePHP-3 and you are following Cake-2 link just follow http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

Comment: Please show your AppController code too. Need to check the `initialize()` function where you've declared the Auth component.

Comment: `parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'loginRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Pages',
                'action' => 'success'
            ],
            'logoutRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Pages',
                'action' => 'index',
                'home'
            ],
   'authenticate' => [
    'Form' => [
     'fields' => [
      'username' => 'username',
      'password' => 'password'
     ]
    ]
   ]
        ]);`

Comment: SOLVED: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29545863/login-auth-identify-always-false-on-cakephp-3